# Json value in SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server

I want to  remove spaces using below query.There is an spaces in the second(" DEF") and third input values("GHI ").How can we remove the spaces?

Original query:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
   openjson('[{"value":"12","text":"ABC"},
              {"value":"31","text":" DEF"},
              {"value":"25","text":"GHI "}]', '$' )
WITH ([NUMBER] nvarchar(100) '$.text')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the [TRIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql) function.

```
SELECT TRIM([NUMBER])
FROM openjson('[{"value":"12","text":"ABC"},
            {"value":"31","text":" DEF"},
            {"value":"25","text":"GHI "}]', '$' )
WITH ([NUMBER] nvarchar(100) '$.text')
```

Depending on your version of SQL Server, LTRIM() and RTRIM() can be nested to provide similar functionality.

```
SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM([NUMBER]))
FROM openjson('[{"value":"12","text":"ABC"},
            {"value":"31","text":" DEF"},
            {"value":"25","text":"GHI "}]', '$' )
WITH ([NUMBER] nvarchar(100) '$.text')
```

Comment: Thanks.I used ltrim and rtrim function.